# Running perl script on AWS EC2 linux AMI continually

Tags: linux, perl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, daemon

I have used various snippets of code to build a system which

1. listens to a port for incoming TCP data (using a perl script), writes this data to a log file.
2. calls and runs a PHP script to consume the log file and write it to an RDS MySQL DB

I have a GPS device configured to send the data to the elastic IP of my AWS EC2 Server

It works fine, and when i run via SSH

```
perl portlistener.pl
```

it does it's job fine, happily working away.

The only way I can stop the script running is by closing the terminal window, ending my SSH session. What I need to do, is keep it running at all times, and to implement a start, stop and restart facility. Do i need to create a daemon?

I know PHP, but until now have never worked with Perl. I'm also not that familiar with command line, other than installing updates, navigating and editing single files etc.

Thanks in advance for any help, or for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Take a look at [Daemon-Control](https://metacpan.org/pod/Daemon::Control).

Comment: Solved it I think using Deamon::Control

Comment: Yeah I tried but It wouldn't let me answer it myself within a certain time limit of asking

Answer (score 1):

Solved it I think!

installed CPAN http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/

Using CPAN, installed Deamon::Control

Then created a new program as below (portlistener_launcher.pl), and ran it as SU.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Daemon::Control;

$ENV{PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN} = 10;
$ENV{PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS} = 1000;

Daemon::Control->new({
    name => 'portlistener',
    program => 'perl /home/ec2-user/portlistener/portlistener.pl',
    fork => 2,
    pid_file => '/var/run/portlistener.pid',
    stdout_file => '/var/log/portlistener.log',
    stderr_file => '/var/log/portlistener.log',

})->run;
```

There's probably a neater way of doing it, but it seems to work, and I can stop/start it like so:

```
perl portlistener_launcher.pl start
```

Answer (score 0):

If the terminal window is the only task, you can use the nohup command, e.g. 
http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/
To terminate the listener you can kill an appropriate running process or processes.

An implementation of daemon does not ensure its permanent running. It can crash or might be killed from someone. To guarantee the permanent daemon running you must implement a 24x7 monitoring of this daemon and automatic restarting of it.